# Mantra for Nar-Narayana vision

Tags: mantras

What is the mantra mentioned in the scriptures that can be chanted for Nar-Narayana? So that a devotee can get their darshan.

Comment: there are several if not many

Comment: If so, can you please post as answer? @SwamiVishwananda